# Saving data from JSON to Realm

Tags: ios, json, swift, realm, alamofire

I'm new to Realm and I'm having some trouble trying to save JSON data from WebService to my Realm DB.

This is the JSON:

```
{  
   "Programacao":[  
      {  
         "Dia":"5",
         "Idp":"1833",
         "Programa":"T\u00e1 Na Hora",
         "Inicio":"06:00",
         "Final":"08:00",
         "Data":"08\/04\/2016"
      },
      {  
         "Dia":"5",
         "Idp":"1834",
         "Programa":"Bom dia Chiru",
         "Inicio":"08:00",
         "Final":"09:00",
         "Data":"08\/04\/2016"
      },
      {  
         "Dia":"5",
         "Idp":"1835",
         "Programa":"Conex\u00e3o",
         "Inicio":"09:00",
         "Final":"11:00",
         "Data":"08\/04\/2016"
      },
      {  
         "Dia":"5",
         "Idp":"1836",
         "Programa":"As Mais Pedidas",
         "Inicio":"11:00",
         "Final":"12:00",
         "Data":"08\/04\/2016"
      },
      {  
         "Dia":"5",
         "Idp":"1837",
         "Programa":"Casa da Sogra",
         "Inicio":"12:00",
         "Final":"13:00",
         "Data":"08\/04\/2016"
      },
      {  
         "Dia":"5",
         "Idp":"1838",
         "Programa":"Canal Livre",
         "Inicio":"13:00",
         "Final":"15:00",
         "Data":"08\/04\/2016"
      },
      {  
         "Dia":"5",
         "Idp":"18",
         "Programa":"Batid\u00e3o da Chiru",
         "Inicio":"15:00",
         "Final":"17:00",
         "Data":"08\/04\/2016"
      },
      {  
         "Dia":"5",
         "Idp":"1827",
         "Programa":"Sul Bandas",
         "Inicio":"17:00",
         "Final":"19:00",
         "Data":"08\/04\/2016"
      },
      {  
         "Dia":"5",
         "Idp":"1828",
         "Programa":"Voz do Brasil",
         "Inicio":"19:00",
         "Final":"20:00",
         "Data":"08\/04\/2016"
      },
      {  
         "Dia":"5",
         "Idp":"1831",
         "Programa":"Al\u00f4 Chiru",
         "Inicio":"20:00",
         "Final":"23:59",
         "Data":"08\/04\/2016"
      }
   ]
}
```

I've created the following structure:

Realm Object Class:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class ROListing: Object {     // Programação da Rádio

  dynamic var id              = 0

  dynamic var showName        = ""
  dynamic var showId          = ""

  dynamic var showStartTime   = ""
  dynamic var showEndTime     = ""

  dynamic var showNumericDate = ""
  dynamic var showDate        = ""

  override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
  }

}
```

Object manipulation classes:

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import Foundation

class Listing: ResponseJSONObjectSerializable {

  var showName        :String?    // nomePrograma
  var showId          :String?    // idp

  var showStartTime   :String?    // inicioPrograma
  var showEndTime     :String?    // finalPrograma

  var showNumericDate :String?    // dia
  var showDate        :String?    // data

  required init?(json: JSON) {

    self.showName         = json["Programa"].string
    self.showId           = json["Idp"].string

    self.showStartTime    = json["Inicio"].string
    self.showEndTime      = json["Final"].string

    self.showNumericDate  = json["Dia"].string
    self.showDate         = json["Data"].string

  }

  required init() { }
}

class ListingArray: ResponseJSONObjectSerializable {

  var showArray: [Listing]?       // Programacao

  required init?(json: JSON) {

    if let arrayJson = json["Programacao"].array {
      self.showArray = []

      for json in arrayJson {
        let instance = Listing(json: json)
        self.showArray?.append(instance!)
      }

    }

  }

  required init() { }
}
```

Connecting with the WebService through:

```
func getRadioListing(success: () -> ()) {

    guard let url = apiController.createURLWithComponentsForListingsWith(appId: "63") else {
      print("Invlaid URL!")
      return
    }

    print(url)

    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseObject {
      (response: Response<ListingArray, NSError>) in

      if let jsonResults = response.result.value {
        self.listings = jsonResults

        for listing in self.listings.showArray! {
          RealmObjectManager.sharedInstance.createUpdateDB(withListing: listing)
        }

        success()

      } else {
        print("Error parsing JSON!")
        return
      }
    }

  }
```

And lastly, the method for actually saving the objects to the Realm DB.

```
  func createUpdateDB(withListing listing: Listing) {

    print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.path!)

    if self.listingArray.count == 0 {

      do {

        try self.realm.write {

          let newListing = ROListing()

          newListing.showName = listing.showName!
          newListing.showId = listing.showId!

          newListing.showStartTime = listing.showStartTime!
          newListing.showEndTime = listing.showEndTime!

          newListing.showNumericDate = listing.showNumericDate!
          newListing.showDate = listing.showDate!

          self.realm.add(newListing)
        }

      } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error creating Listing DB: \(error.userInfo)")
      }
    }
  }
```

However I can't get all the shows into the DB. Anyone could help me out here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cole might have already nailed the problem here, but just in case, can you please post what error log you're getting when you try and insert all of the shows? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's a problem with my logic! I don't get any error but only the first element [0] is being saved. I think I need to check if my listingArray is empty (or nil?) first and then perform the write. Thanks Cole Campbell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for sure without the error log, but it does appear that you will have a problem due to your primary key. Realm enforces uniqueness for the primary key, so if you try to add an object to the realm with the same primary key as an existing object of the same type it will break. As far as I can tell, you're setting the primary key to 0 by default but you aren't updating it with a unique value before saving.

If you just need a unique identifier for each object and order doesn't matter, this is a good solution:

```
dynamic var id: String = NSUUID().UUIDString
```